# Let A ⊂ (X,T). Then Ā = A iff A is closed.

Tags: general-topology, analysis

Does this it mean if we take the closure of a closed set, the result will be equal to an open set?

I’m assuming that all adherent points of the closed set Ā exclude the boundary as the points x that lie on the boundary don’t have neighborhoods (not sure) therefore the only points will be the interior of A “the open set A” if we take the set of all adherent points of Ā.

I have stated my assumption as it might give some hints for where I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Not all sets are either open or closed, some are neither open nor closed (and some are even both!). Instead, look at how the closure operator is defined.

Comment: Sorry i made the mistake to extend this problem for all sets. in reality i'm just concerning about this set.

Comment: If you mean that $\overline{A}$ is the set of adherence points of $A$, and closed is the complement of an open set, then see my answer way below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure of $A$ is the smallest CLOSED set contains $A$; then $Cl(A)$ is closed by definition. On the other hand, if $A$ is closed then the smallest closed set that $A$ is subset of that set, must be $A$ itself thus $Cl(A)=A$ if and only if $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 1):

So the question is basically asking this:

If $(X, \mathcal{T})$ is a topological space, and $A \subseteq X$ (i.e., $A$ is a subset of $X$), then you need to prove $A$ is closed iff $\overline{A} = A$.

It seems from your notation that you think $A \subseteq (X, \mathcal{T})$ means $A$ is open.  This isn't true.  If you write $A \in \mathcal{T}$, then that means $A$ is open.  But writing $A \subseteq (X, \mathcal{T})$ just means $A \subseteq X$.

You can use multiple equivalent definitions of closure here.

One definition of the closure of a set $A$ is $\overline{A} = A \cup A'$, where $A'$ is the set of limit points of $A$.

You could also use $\overline{A} = \{ x \in X \mid U \cap A \neq \emptyset \text{ for all } U \in \mathcal{T} \text{ with } x \in U \}$.  That is, $\overline{A}$ is the set of $x \in X$ such that all open neighborhoods around $x$ intersect $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer one confusion i had of the topological space notation is now clear, but just for the sake of conviction the equality Ā = A means that the right hand of that term is closed?

Comment: @ByronAguirre Well, since it's an equality, they're both closed.

Comment: @ByronAguirre Yes, as GPerez also noted, since $\overline{A}$ is closed, and $\overline{A} = A$, that means $A$ is closed.  When we say $\overline{A} = A$, we are saying $\overline{A}$ and $A$ are the **same thing**.  So if the thing is closed, then the same thing is closed (I know that sounds like a dumb observation, but that is what is going on).  It's like saying "if a set $A$ is closed, then the set $A$ is closed".  Well of course $A$ is closed if $A$ is closed.  By saying $\overline{A} = A$, we are just saying they are the same set, so if one is closed, the other must be.

Comment: @user46944 Of course that question of the equality was a dump question I just mess it up when I was trying to prove by considering A as a complement set from a given space X minus other set  and then taking the remaining set A all its contact points; having only the interior of A. Thanks for the replies. Couldn't vote up as this is my first post.

Comment: @user46944 That's not quite a justification. If you really want to prove that if (two sets) $A=B$ then $A$ and $B$ have the same properties, you have to get into the definition of equality for sets, and see whether the property is in fact preserved. The fact is that we define set equality so that this works out, but there's equalities among other objects (say, equivalence classes) that don't necessarily preserve every property we can think of.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose that $\overline{A}$ is defined as the set of all adherence points of $A$ (i.e. all $x \in X$ such that for every open set $O$ that contains $x$ we have $O \cap A \neq \emptyset$), and a set is closed iff it is the complement of an open set.

So suppose $A$ is closed. We always know that all points of $A$ are adherence points of $A$ trivially (i.e. $A \subseteq \overline{A}$), so suppose that $x \notin A$. Then as $A$ is closed, $O = X \setminus A$ is open and contains $x$, but this $O$ misses $A$. This shows that $x$ is not an adherence point of $A$, or $x \notin \overline{A}$. So $x \in A$ implies $x \in \overline{A}$ and $x \notin A$ implies $x \notin \overline{A}$. So $A = \overline{A}$ as required.

Suppose then that $A = \overline{A}$. Then $A$ is closed: let $x \in X \setminus A$. Then $x \notin \overline{A}$, so $x$ is not adherence point of $A$, so there is some open set $O_x$ such that $x \in O_x$ and $O_x \cap A = \emptyset$. But this means that $O_x \subseteq X \setminus A$, and as all points of $X \setminus A$ are contained in such an $O_x$, $X \setminus A = \cup \{O_x: x \in X \setminus A\}$, which is a union of open sets, so $X \setminus A$ is open, and $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost by definition. Anyway...

$$\bar A=\bigcap_{\{C\text{ close }\mid C\supseteq A\}}C$$
but $A$ is close, and is the smallest element of $\{C\text{ close }\mid C\supseteq A\}$ therefore
$$\bigcap_{\{C\text{ close }\mid C\supseteq A\}}C=A\implies \bar A=A$$

Comment: You only proved the "$A$ is closed $\implies$ $\overline{A} = A$" direction.

Comment: It seems the OP means closure as the set of adherence points of $A$, not defined as the minimal closed set containing $A$.